# How to disabled user hidden id in form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, security

I need to update the database based on the user ID. I am storing the user ID in a hidden form field on the page, but I have learned that anyone can change the value of the hidden field using the browser inspector.

How can I securely update the user record without it being tampered with?

Comment: You can't. You need to check (in the backedn) if the user has the access to change that user's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to store such IDs in session. 
In this case anybody (including hackers) know only the session ID, but not the user ID. Normally session ID is randomly generated and it is impossible to guess other one.

Comment: I need that id in mysql: to use in where caluse.

Comment: You can get it from session. I can not give more detailed answer before I see any actual code.

Comment: session ID is randomly generated than how can i match.
I am planing to create one function encryption and decryption. Got suggestion from facebook group. 
What you say about it?

Comment: Or generate one session make it array!
array will contain all user information.

Comment: PHP will take care of it. Review basic session examples http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php . Make sure the session is started then you can use global $_SESSION array to set/get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guid instead of Id. 
It is impossible to guess right Guid

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your sensitive information in sessions like `user id`, `user email`.

Depending upon that you can fetch information from database.

Hidden variables can be modified by console as you stated correctly.

Users cannot modify session variables and thus they are secure to store user (session) specific information.

For example, if your site has a logged in user `abc`, whose id is `7`.

Fetch his data from MySQL database like:

```
SELECT * FROM userData WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode and decode your value,

for me I created and array for that with some random values like and I inserted my private value in to that,

```
array([test] => sudhakar, [name] => 'foo', [value] => foobar);
```

and I encoded with base 64 it will return a random numbers and serialize that one also.

and add it as hidden value.